# BeautifulSoup find() returns odd data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to get data off a website. I can find the data I want but when I print it, it comes out as "-1" The value in the field is 32.27. Here is the code I'm using

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv

symbols = {'451020'}

with open('industry_pe.csv', "ab") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['Industry','PE'])
    for s in symbols:
        try:
            url = 'https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/markets_sectors/sectors/industries.jhtml?tab=learn&industry='
            full = url + s
            response = requests.get(full)
            html = response.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

            for PE in soup.find("div", {"class": "sec-fundamentals"}):
                print PE
                #IndPE = PE.find("td")
                #print IndPE
```

When I print PE it returns this...

```
    <h2>
                        Industry Fundamentals
                      <span>AS OF 03/08/2018</span>
</h2>


<table summary="" class="data-tbl">
<colgroup>
<col class="col1" />
<col class="col2" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col"></th>
<th scope="col"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row" class="align-left"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javasc
ript:openPopup('https://www.fidelity.com//webcontent/ap010098-etf-content/18.01/
help/research/learn_er_glossary_3.shtml#priceearningsratio',420,450);return fals
e;">P/E (Last Year GAAP Actual)</a></th>
<td>



                        32.27


           </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row" class="align-left"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javasc
ript:openPopup('https://www.fidelity.com//webcontent/ap010098-etf-content/18.01/
help/research/learn_er_glossary_3.shtml#priceearningsratio',420,450);return fals
e;">P/E (This Year's Estimate)</a>.....
```

I want to get the value 32.27 from 'td' but when i use the code i have commented out to get and print 'td' it gives me this.

```
-1
None
-1
<td>



                       32.27


           </td>
-1
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method returns the tag which is the first match. Iterating over the contents of a tag, will give you all the tags one by one.

So, to get the `<td>` tags in the table, you should first find the table and store it in a variable. And then iterate over all the `td` tags using `find_all('td')`.

```
table = soup.find("div", {"class": "sec-fundamentals"})
for row in table.find_all('td'):
    print(row.text.strip())
```

Partial Output:

```
32.27
34.80
$122.24B
$3.41
14.14%
15.88%
```

If you want only the first value, you can use this:

```
table = soup.find("div", {"class": "sec-fundamentals"})
value = table.find('td').text.strip()
print(value)
# 32.27
```